# Databricks notebook API: minimize cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks

From the Databricks UI, we can minimize/collapse cells in the top-left corner.

A notebook's content is updated programmatically. The new content is huge and not always needed, so I minimize the cell.

Can I do the same via the Workspace API? Is there any flags to tell that a cell should be minimized by default, when the notebook is imported?